# Have midnight appear at the end of a list of times in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a venue management site and I want to be able to create timeslots where I can input all the available times for shows and then add a show to that timeslot later.

The timeslots will normally run from about 10am to 2am. I'm able to create the timeslots and then order them in ascending order, but that makes the timeslots that start after midnight display at the top. How can I have them appear at the bottom as the last shows of the day.

So far I have this:

`SELECT * FROM TimeSlot ORDER BY start ASC;`

So I want anything from the 'start' column that has a time from 00.00.00 to about 03.00.00 (there is no chance shows will start after this time) to display at the bottom of the list.

It outputs like this:

```
timeId start 
1.     00.00.00
3.     10.00.00
5.     11.00.00
7.     12.00.00 
6.     13.00.00
2.     14.00.00
```

But I want it to look like this:

````
3.     10.00.00
5.     11.00.00
7.     12.00.00 
6.     13.00.00
2.     14.00.00
1.     00.00.00```
````

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional logic in the `order by`:

```
order by (start >= '05:00:00') desc,  -- seems like a good cutoff
         start
```

This puts times starting at 05:00:00 at the top, in order, with times after midnight following.